# How to add library in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to add a 3rd party library to my project.
But it keeps on giving this error:

```
Error:(10, 0) Could not find property 'VERSION_NAME' on project ':library'.
```

I am adding [Floating action button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) library

Can someone mention me the proper steps how do I import it?

Comment: Can you please tell me why close?

Comment: Add the content of your build files, please.

Comment: Just add the dependency to your build.gradle. Have you done this ?

Comment: if not then please add this line : compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0' to dependencies of your build.gradle & Click on sync

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button#user-content-usage) in the link you provided. You just simply paste this into your **Build.gradle** file

```
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
```

If you want to learn more about android studio, check out [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/tools/android-studio/getting-started-with-android-studio.html) tutorial I made on getting started with android studio :D