# Unable to add Library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-gallery, universal-image-loader

It might be possible that this question looks smiler to this:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272536/how-to-add-library-in-android-studio)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317660/how-to-add-librarys-in-android-studio-1-1-0)

But I didn't get what I want.
I'm Creating a simple custom image gallery app in which I'm showing images on GridView. And for this I took help from this [Post](http://androhub.com/select-and-share-multiple-images/#comment-265). In which they said how to add **UniversalImageLoader library**.
But unfortunately I'm not able to add this library as it is mentioned.
I have tried this [also](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio). I want to add this **UniversalImageLoader library** in my project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfPgx6c5wgA) link to add a library in Android studio. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the library(.jar) in the libs folder and then add the reference for the same in the build.gradle.

This can be done by two ways:

1>By manually adding it to dependencies using

```
compile files('libs/libray_name.jar')
```

2>Or by right clicking on the jar and selecting the option "add as library".

For more detailed steps do visit [this page](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup) on UIL.

Answer (score 0):

You can just paste this line of code in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

for using the universal image loader library.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a library into a project by simple steps [**described here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954703/android-studio-import-already-compiled-c-library/33957617#33957617)

or you can follow this [**method**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612132/4776577)

First one is easy and accurate.